# Tab overflow on Area51 in Firefox (Ubuntu)

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, area-51

This is a relatively minor bug, but a bug nonetheless. I use Firefox 8.0 on Ubuntu 11.10, and when I open Area51 the text on the "All Proposals" tab overflows. It looks like "All Proposals" is supposed to fit on one line, but it does not. Perhaps the default font is wider on Ubuntu?

[image]